# Piping equivalent on powershell

Tags: git, powershell

On unix, I'd run a command like this:

```sh
$ git diff origin/master origin/dev -- <file/dir> | git apply -
```

Which would basically apply all the differences between the two branches to my current working copy.

I love using this command, but my coworker is on a Windows machine, and powershell apparently doesn't do `|` pipes the same way.

What's a one-liner in powershell that would let us do this same command?

Answer (score 1):

As with most things PowerShell you might want to investigate whether there's a module that might help you. For example, the best known is probably [posh-git](https://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/)

You can solve your problem more directly, though, because if you're using git on Windows, you are almost certainly using Git for Windows, which includes a bash shell. The standard install adds "Git Bash here" to the context menu, so from Windows explorer you can open the shell in a folder of your choice.

Comment: Right, git bash is a valid way to go. I'd still like to know though, what's the general pattern to do "piping" in powershell similarly? If I have output from one command, how can I pipe it into another in a one-liner?

Comment: A good overview of pipelines in powershell is available in [Help About_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks Walter. In particular, the section here is relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2#using-native-commands-in-the-pipeline